# How to auto input MySQL data (input column 2 data to auto input column1 data with same column) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, multiple-columns

[image]

Here I had 3 column
I want to insert all of my data from img_id to img_parent_id

Evrrything but didn't get it.

Comment: `update your_table set img_parent_id=img_id ;`

Comment: I have put you what you can do with link if it is ok don't forget to check it

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE Syntax

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

**For example :** in your case

```
UPDATE table 
SET img_parent_id=img_id;
```

**RUN :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/116
Other Option :

```
UPDATE table 
SET img_parent_id=img_id
WHERE img_id IN(12,14,16);
```

**RUN** : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/115

**BLOG URL :** https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: if it is correct hit the check